# Saving data with dataWithPDFInsideRect: just makes a black pdf

Tags: cocoa, pdf, isight

I have a QTCaptureView and Im trying to save the view as a picture. So far I have this:

```
 NSRect rect = [outputView bounds];
 NSData *viewData = [outputView dataWithPDFInsideRect:rect];
 [viewData writeToFile:@"/test.pdf" atomically:YES];
```

but for some reason when I save instead of seeing a picture of my vie (iSight Camera) I see a black pdf file.

Thanks for any help

Comment: There's no point in using `dataWithPDFInsideRect:` for that, since the view isn't drawing any vectors. You want a raster capture here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTCaptureView isn't meant to be used in this way due to the way it is optimized. You'll need to do single-frame-grabbing the QTKit way: [Creating a Single-Frame Grabbing Application](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW34).